# How can I make sure a batch variable must equal certain values?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I want to write an if not statement in a batch file to make sure that a variable MUST be equal to certain values. Like lets say that if I want a variable for sex and I give the user the option for

```
set /p sex=Sex:
```

and I want to make sure that they can only put in values like Male/Female or male/female or m/f or it will loop back to the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
:EnterSex
ECHO Valid values are: (M)ale / (F)emale
SET /P sex=Sex:

REM Validate user entered value.
SET Result=null
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`ECHO ~M~Male~F~Female~ ^| FINDSTR /I ~%sex%~`) DO SET Result=%%A
IF "%Result%" == "null" (
    ECHO The value entered is not valid.
    GOTO EnterSex
)

REM If we get here the value entered was valid.
```

So in the above, the valid values are wrapped in a delimiter (`~` in this example) and then you pipe all possible results to a case insensitive match (the `FINDSTR` command) which wraps the user input with the delimiters.

If a match is found, it will be set to the `%Result%` variable, otherwise the value will remain `null`.

Comment: so how could I reset what they entered to `null`? It looks like the way your code is working is that it only echos The value entered is not valid. How could I reset the value entered and also send them back up to reenter (go back up to the set /p )

Answer (score 1):

Use expansion search and replace (case insensitve) to see if the entered value is contained within a list of valid values. Note the required space at the beginning and end of the valid list.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "validSex= m f male female "
:getSex
set "sex="
set /p "sex=Sex: "
if "!validSex: %sex% =!" equ "!validSex!" goto :getSex
```

Comment: That's a pretty clever idea.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:SEXY
set /p sex=Sex:

for %%a in (MALE,FEMALE,F,M) DO (
    if /I %sex% EQU %%a (
        set "selected_sex=%%a"
        GOTO OK:
    )
)
GOTO SEXY:
:OK
    echo you are: %selected_sex%
```